# Installing Bitcoin Armory on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, armory

I installed Bitcoin Armory on Ubuntu 13.10. I get the following output when I try to run it:

```
root@cloud-server-07:/BitcoinArmory# python ArmoryQt.py
********************************************************************************
Loading Armory Engine:
   Armory Version:       0.91.1
   PyBtcWallet  Version: 1.35
Detected Operating system: Linux
   OS Variant            : ('Ubuntu', '13.10', 'saucy')
   User home-directory   : /root
   Satoshi BTC directory : /root/.bitcoin/
   Armory home dir       : /root/.armory/
   LevelDB directory     : /root/.armory/databases
   Armory settings file  : /root/.armory/ArmorySettings.txt
   Armory log file       : /root/.armory/armorylog.txt
   Do wallet checking    : True
ArmoryQt.py: cannot connect to X server
```

Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You should not run Armory as root. If you want to run armory as another user, pick a user other than root. You can use "sux" (which you can apt-get install) to become that new user.

Comment: Why should you not run armory as root?

Answer (score 0):

The installation went fine, but the last line `ArmoryQt.py: cannot connect to X server` is the error. Somehow the program cannot be shown in a window. When this happens in an ssh session, you need to relogin with the `-X` or `-Y` option. In your case, I think you have to look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175611/cannot-connect-to-x-server-when-running-app-with-sudo) answer:

> You need to allow the root user access to the X server:
>
> ```
> xhost local:root
> ```
>
> And point the command to the right `DISPLAY`:
>
> ```
>  sudo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY gedit /etc/profile
> ```

Comment: I'm connecting to this machine through SSH. 'xhost local:root' returns 'xhost:  unable to open display ""'

Comment: I'm actually trying to run armory as daemon and use JSON-RPC commands using armoryd.py. That gives the error: File "armoryd.py", line 55, in <module>
    from txjsonrpc.auth import wrapResource
ImportError: No module named txjsonrpc.auth

Comment: Hmm, are you sshing with the `-X` or `-Y` option?Otherwise you'll never be able to open a display.

Comment: Isn't `txjsonrpc` needed for Armory? Im not into this material, but from what I read in the past couple of minutes I think it is. From there the `txjsonrpc.auth` you're missing should be added, and that error be resolved

Comment: Yes true. It seems I need to install txjsonrpc. Can't figure out how to get it though. Thanks a lot btw

Comment: I just cloned the repo https://github.com/oubiwann/txjsonrpc to my BitcoinArmory folder but I still get the same error. I think I need to install it